# Windows 2012R2 move folders users, ProgramData, ProgramFiles to the D

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012-r2

We would like to place the folders “Users”, “ProgramData”, “Program Files” and “Program Files (x86)” on the D drive for a non AD integrated server. We have already tried many options however have yet to find a viable one.

Is this possible? We’ve read some articles which strongly advise against it.

Options we have tested and the result:

- Symbolic links – This breaks Windows update because of the hard links in Windows
- Added GPO settings that achieve this on AD environment to registry manually – This works well for the “Users” folder. However the “ProgramData” folder has some hard links in it. – Is this an issue?
  From the options we’ve tried the one with the registry settings seems the most viable. Is this supported? Are there any issues?
  If there is another way which is viable and supported please let us know as well.

Background:

We’re a small hosting company which provides cloud services like a online workspace through RDP. Our customers have little to no IT knowledge. We want to create a clear barrier between system data and customer data, without limiting the customer or educating them in the inner workings of the Windows system.

Thank you for your replies and input,

Davy